# Should I or could I use Spring within EJB's

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ejb

I am working in a firm that is new to java and I am the only java programmer and I need to write about 10 systems within a few months.. The firm has 2 other programmers that know basic java. Not Spring or anything like that.

I did a number of prototypes using Spring, hibernate and MySQL.  By the SA's are pushing us to use EJB's (we just got JBoss). So now the manger is thinking about having me move the DAO and Hibernate layer into EJB's.

So we will use Spring for the MVC (web) and then make it do EJB class for all data access so the Jr Programmers don't have to know how to access MySQL and the AS/400.

So for my question.  I would like to know if I can use Spring within the EJBs..  Stuff like JDBCTemplate plus Hibernate.  What I am trying is moving the DAO layer right inside a EJB..

Can this be done? if so should it be done?

Comment: SAs ? System admins or system analysts ?

Comment: LMAO.. I know it is to late to quit.. The System admins are pushing to it so the front end-programmers can just do the front-end work and have EJBs using the JNDI data sources in JBoss.

Comment: divorce your back end from your front end, and leat each go his own way (and technology stack, is they so choose). be better for everyone.

Comment: yes radi but can I move the Spring DAO Layer right into EJB's

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring within EJBs but it is rather complex and does not bring benefits over using spring alone. I do not recommend to do that.

Comment: Thanks Henry... The System admins are pushing to it so the front end-programmers can just do the front-end work and have EJBs using the JNDI data sources in JBoss. So I was thinking I can just take the DAO layer from Spring and have them called within the EJB's

Comment: Separation of presentation and business logic is good but EJBs are not the only way to achieve it and if you just push the DAO layer down there is still business logic above the EJBs.

Comment: So true Henry but the push is to put all DAO stuff into EJBs and then call them from Springs Service layer.   I just don't know if Spring will run in EJB or if this is the right way to go..

Comment: Well examine the integration chapter in the Spring manual and get a better picture I'd say. My opinion: if you keep using Spring then Spring is going to stay "in the lead". EJB technology was not built to co-exist with other frameworks, it was designed to do its own tricks only which includes advanced transaction management, its own injection mechanism (CDI) and persistence using the JPA specification.

Comment: Spring runs in an EJB but you have to be careful with the lifecycle of spring beans vs. EJBs. Each EJB has its own naming context so if you do JNDI lookups for the initialization of spring beans (i.e. to get data sources) you must make sure this code executes in the scope of the EJB. Another area of fun are transactions. If part of the business logic is above the EJB layer you cannot use the container transactions.

Comment: Thansk Gimby, So you feel that I should just use Spring+Hibernate AND use JNDI configured datasources.. I should NOT move the Spring+Hibernate layer inside the EJB's

Answer (score 2):

As a lightweight container, Spring is often considered an EJB replacement. We do believe that for many if not most applications and use cases, Spring as a container, combined with its rich supporting functionality in the area of transactions, ORM and JDBC access, is a better choice than implementing equivalent functionality via an EJB container and EJBs.

However, it is important to note that using Spring does not prevent you from using EJBs. In fact, Spring makes it much easier to access EJBs and implement EJBs and functionality within them. Additionally, using Spring to access services provided by EJBs allows the implementation of those services to later transparently be switched between local EJB, remote EJB, or POJO (plain old Java object) variants, without the client code having to be changed.

Here is the link:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/ejb.html

Comment: new link http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. Take a Look at [Chapter 22](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html) of the [Spring Framework Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) that deals with EJBS. You can even use [`@EJB` annotations in your Spring POJOS](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/1.2/html/Spring_Developer_Guide/ch07s05s02.html) and [`@Autowired` annotations in your EJB layer](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/1.2/html/Spring_Developer_Guide/ch07s05.html#id4929388).

Programmers tend to tell you that everytime you mix Spring with EJB a Pink Dolphin dies... Well, I have done it quite often and they are still alive.

Comment: It becomes a mess though; then you have a whopping -three- ways of injecting resources into EJBs (old style, CDI and Spring autowired). The novices are going to go nuts trying to understand such a divided system.

Comment: Anthony.. I know I can call EJBs from Spring but I am asking if I should put Spring in a EJB like for JDBCTemplate etc etc... the DAO layer will be moved within EJBs... what do you think about it

Comment: Your question about if you *should* has been pretty strongly answered already by other stackoverflow fellows. If you are only doing this only to reuse a DAO layer then I'm with the crowd. I've no experience with `JDBCTemplates` inside EJBS, actually I've always done it the other way around. Local EJB DAO Layer (using JPA) + Remote Business EJB Layer consumed by many applications, including *Spring MVC*, *BlazeDS + Flex* and non Spring apps. Although I Agree with @Gimby that this can get messy, I can assure you that if you keep your layers separated, junior programmers will get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your requirements, think about the design of your system - do YOU think a mixup of Spring and Java EE is the best practice in your case? Is this system managable, extensible, maintainable in production?

You can use Spring+Hibernate AND use JNDI configured datasources. You can even do this by using tomcat only.

I can't see a good design reason to put just the DAO layer into EJB, so think about your design and prepare arguments for it. IMHO, this is a mixup and just makes the system more complicated and errornous.

To move your whole business and persistence layer to EJB may be reasonable, it depends on your concrete situation. Try to write a pro vs. con list. Whats the benefit, whats a con.

Comment: Thanks Burna.. I never liked it..I think we should also just Stay with Spring+Hibernate and use JNDI datasources but some of it so we can have common code in the EJB that calls common stuff like user information.  If I have it in a EJB then every programmer don't have to know how or where to look up the information....

Comment: cool, yes, common services should be refactored to a centralized location. Maybe the term SOA sounds good to your admins. So youre doing a service oriented architecture, where services are accesible via EJB, imho this sounds reasonable.

Comment: we are thinking about moving the Spring, DAO layer into EJB so the programmers will not acces the database the programmers will call EJB's that will use Spring, Hiberante etc??

Comment: ah! you think about moving your Spring - Business logic Beans and DAOs, to EJB? This may be reasonable and ok. This would be a physical separation of the client tier and the business tier, which is absolutely legitimate. This would be a big difference, if so add this to your question.